# Jquery datepicker to show events on mouseenter with different events for each button

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, calendar, datepicker

I want to show events in Jquery calendar, in my code i have 4 buttons each button is related with a membber, Now when i hover mouse on sam(member name) then events related to sam must be showing in calendar, when i hover on riya then events related to riya must be shown in calendar. here is my code. I want date format as i mentioned in code. these are the values from my database so if I do something like new Date("2011-07-13") this is not working. thanks in advance, any help will be appreciated.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>cal </title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery-ui.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <button class="cal">Riya</button>
    <button class="cal">Sam</button>
    <button class="cal">Kishor</button>
    <button class="cal">jack</button>

    <div id="datepicker" style="display:none"><div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var events = [ 
    { Id:"1", Title: "riya's metting ", event_date: '2014-07-13', member_id:"1"}, 
    { Id:"2", Title: "sam meeting ", event_date:"2014-07-14", member_id:"2"},
    { Id:"3", Title: "kishor meeting", event_date: "2014-07-15",member_id: "3"},
    { Id:"4", Title: "jack meeting", event_date: "2014-07-23",member_id: "4"},
     { Id:"5", Title: "riya's meeting again", event_date: "2014-07-25",member_id: "1"}
];
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `id` must be unique. Your `HTML` is invalid. You're using jquery ui datepicker, i doubt whether a datepicker can be used as a calender...

Comment: Sir no matter's. Ok wait i will change it now.

Comment: I strongly recommend to take a look at jQuery FullCalendar plugin: http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/.

Comment: Sir i have seen , also seen some of the examples to show calendar events using jquery but i am facing problem in fetching id'd because in my code i have ng-loop(for loop) so riya,sam, kishor,jack are looping in class cal i am not getting how to show events when class is same for all members because <button class="cal">{{user}}</button> will repeat. n i have more users so cant use id for each user too.

Comment: @andreivictor I am not getting why to create new oblect here and how it creates - Date: new Date("02/13/2011") I have saved my date in events array with simple  event_date: '2014-07-13' format. for this reason how can i change this in my array.

Comment: Refer jquery ui datepicker API documentation. You are using unsupported attributes !